# How do I get this Right outer join to work?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, sapb1

I'm attempting to show all sales orders and, if they have them, the delivery note. I've got a query showing all orders but no matter how I join it to the next table, I continue to get results for only orders with delivery notes. I want `NULL` to be present for delivery notes if there are none on record.

I've tried left, right, and inner joins and they're all returning the same number of results which baffles me. I thought I had an understanding of joins before today.

This part shows how many sales orders exist. I want all results from this to appear in the next query

```
select t0.docnum SalesOrder, t1.itemcode, t1.linenum rdr1line
from ordr t0 inner join rdr1 t1 on t1.docentry = t0.docentry
where t0.CANCELED = 'N';
```

This part shows how many sales orders exist with a Delivery Note, but is not including orders that don't have delivery notes.

```
select t0.docnum SalesOrder, t1.itemcode, t2.docnum DelivNoteNum, t3.baseline inv1base, t1.linenum rdr1line, t3.linenum dln1line
from ordr t0 inner join rdr1 t1 on t1.docentry = t0.docentry
right outer join odln t2 on t2.docentry = t1.trgetentry
right outer join dln1 t3 on t3.docentry = t2.docentry and t3.baseline = t1.linenum and t3.ItemCode = t1.ItemCode
where t0.CANCELED = 'N' and t2.canceled = 'N';
```

Expected results should be the same number of rows in each table. Actual results are only ordered with delivery notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `left join`, not `right join`.  If you want all orders then start with that table.  Filters on subsequent tables should go into the `on` clause:

```
select t0.docnum SalesOrder, t1.itemcode, t2.docnum DelivNoteNum,
       t3.baseline inv1base, t1.linenum rdr1line, t3.linenum dln1line   
from ordr t0 left join
     rdr1 t1
     on t1.docentry = t0.docentry left join
     odln t2
     on t2.docentry = t1.trgetentry and t2.canceled = 'N' left join
     dln1 t3
     on t3.docentry = t2.docentry and
        t3.baseline = t1.linenum and
       t3.ItemCode = t1.ItemCode
where t0.CANCELED = 'N';
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I was trying to achieve. Was the reason I kept getting the same results no matter the join because I had my filters all residing in the where clause?

Comment: I also found 

where (t0.CANCELED = 'N' or t2.CANCELED = 'N' or t4.Canceled = 'N')

 gets the same desired result.